# Riesz's representation of a k-current

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-measure-theory

Reading "Introduction to GMT" by Simon, at page 136 he says that thanks to Riesz's representation theorem we can view k-currents ar Radon measures, or to be more precise he says that given a current $T$ on some open set $U$ , there's a Radon measure $\mu_T$ and a measurable function $\widetilde{T}$ such that for evey k-form $\omega$ on $U$:

$$ T(\omega)= \int_U \langle \omega (x) , \widetilde{T} (x) \rangle d \mu_T (x)$$

Now, the question is: what are the components of $\widetilde{T}$? Is there some "explicit" representation of this? We said in class that $\widetilde{T}$ has components $T_\alpha$ such that

$$ T_\alpha (f)= T (f dx_\alpha)$$

but I may have misunderstood, or anyway I didn't understand. Let's say I have:

$$ \omega (x) = f(x) dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + g(x) dx_2 \wedge dx_3 .$$

What is an explicit example of 2-current? Maybe in the form as above, seen as a vector valued Radon easure with some components.

EDIT: I forgot to say that $ T$ must have finite mass, otherwise it's false in general

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a open set of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. For $\omega \in D_{2}(U)$ define 2-current $T(\omega)=\int_{U}d\omega$. Then the components of $\tilde{T}$ are

- $T_{12}(f)=T(fdx^{1} \wedge dx^{2})=\int_{U}\partial_{x^{3}}f dx^{3} \wedge dx^{1} \wedge dx^{2}=\int_{U}\partial_{x^{3}}fdx^{1}\wedge dx^{2} \wedge dx^{3}$.
- $T_{13}(f)=T(fdx^{1} \wedge dx^{3})=\int_{U}\partial_{x^{2}}f dx^{2} \wedge dx^{1} \wedge dx^{3}=-\int_{U}\partial_{x^{2}}fdx^{1}\wedge dx^{2} \wedge dx^{3}.$
- $T_{23}(f)=T(fdx^{1} \wedge dx^{2})=\int_{U}\partial_{x^{1}}f dx^{1} \wedge dx^{2} \wedge dx^{3}$.

For the specified $\omega$,
$$T(\omega)=\int_{U}(\partial_{x^{3}}f +\partial_{x^{1}}g)dx^{1}\wedge dx^{2} \wedge dx^{3}.$$

Comment: Oh ok let me see if I got this. You say: write $\omega$ in coordinates, as sum of simple covectors multiplied by some functions. Like the $\omega$ I chose as an example, we can write it as $\omega= \omega_f + \omega_g$. Then, $T(\omega)= T(\omega_f )+ T(\omega_g)$ and on each component I make $T$ act in that way you described, so that in the end I have that equality you write last. Now, who would be $\widetilde{T}$ and $\mu_T$ from Riesz theorem in this case? I think $\mu_T= dx$, but $\widetilde{T}$ should be a 2-vector right? $T_{12}$, $T_{13}$ etc seem like covector, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: Ok no, I didn't understand. The representation of $T$ through $\widetilde{T}$ and $\mu_T$ should be unique, with $\widetilde{T}$  a k-vector and $\mu_T$ a Radon measure. Also, the duality pairing between a simple k-covector $\nu$ and a simple k-vector $w$ should be $(\nu , w)= det (\nu_i (w_j))$ right? So I don't see who $\widetilde{T}$ is